# Wikipedia with Python

Tags: python, xml, wikipedia

I have this very simple python code to read xml for the wikipedia api:

```
import urllib
from xml.dom import minidom

usock = urllib.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Fractal&prop=links&pllimit=500")
xmldoc=minidom.parse(usock)
usock.close()
print xmldoc.toxml()
```

But this code returns with these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/workspace/wikipediafoundations/src/list.py", line 5, in <module><br>
    xmldoc=minidom.parse(usock)<br>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1918, in parse<br>
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)<br>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 928, in parse<br>
    result = builder.parseFile(file)<br>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 207, in parseFile<br>
    parser.Parse(buffer, 0)<br>
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 62<br>
```

I have no clue as I just learning python. Is there a way to get an error with more detail? Does anyone know the solution? Also, please recommend a better language to do this in.

Thank You,
Venkat Rao

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The URL you're requesting is an HTML representation of the XML that would be returned:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Fractal&prop=links&pllimit=500
```

So the XML parser fails.  You can see this by pasting the above in a browser.  Try adding a `format=xml` at the end:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Fractal&prop=links&pllimit=500&format=xml
```

as documented on the linked page:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

Comment: @user, since @ars's answer solved you problem, **accept it** -- that is, clic on the checkmark-shaped icon on the left of his answer's text.  This is fundamental SO etiquette!